# Spark streaming kafka Couldn't find leader offsets for Set

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I used spark streaming 'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.10:1.6.1' and 'org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.1' to connect to a kafka broker version 0.10.0.1. When I try this code:

```
def messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicsSet)
```

I've received this exception:

```
    INFO consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([stream,0])
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$createDirectStream.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at com.privowny.classification.jobs.StreamingClassification.main(StreamingClassification.groovy:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I've try to search for some answers in this site but it seems left unanswered, could you give me some suggestion what to do? The topic `stream` is not empty.

Comment: This is usually a signal for ZooKeeper problems. Reset ZooKeeper and try again.

Comment: What could be the problem? I 've just started the server as in the quickstart documentation!

Comment: I've had problems where there was a synchronization problem between Kafka and ZooKeeper. Resetting them both solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know from experience that one thing that can cause this error message is if the Spark driver cannot reach the kafka brokers using the brokers' advertised hostname (`advertised.host.name` in `server.properties`). This is the case even if the spark config identifies the kafka brokers using different addresses that work. All the brokers' advertised hostnames have to be reachable from the Spark driver.

This happened to me because the cluster runs in a separate AWS account, the brokers identify themselves using internal DNS records, these had to be copied to the other AWS account. Prior to doing that, I got this error message because the Spark driver couldn't reach the brokers to ask for their latest offsets, even though we use the brokers' private IP addresses in the spark config.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this issue. So you have to change some configuration on your the Kafka.

Go to your the Kafka configuration and config `listeners`;

In the Socket Server Settings section in the format:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://[hostname or IP]:[port]
```

For example:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.24:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running kafka from HDP, so the default port was 6667 instead of 9092, when I switched the port of `bootstrap.servers` to `<hostname>:6667` the issue was resolved.